# phpbb3 How do I get Custom Profile Fields to showup on posts made by users?

Tags: php, phpbb3

I have this code: But it dosn't work.

from viewtopic_body.html

```
<!-- BEGIN custom_fields -->
    <!-- IF postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_FIELD_NAME eq "ingame_name" -->
        <dd><strong>{postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_FIELD_NAME}:</strong> {postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_FIELD_VALUE}</dd>
    <!-- ENDIF -->
<!-- END custom_fields -->
```

My custom field name is called "ingame_username" and is set to display everywhere possible in the options, ive deleted the cache after making changes and still doesn't show.

How do I display is with the code structure above and how can I call it in other parts of the template?

Theres very limited documentation about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree it is not very straight forward, since there are a few options you need to check under ACP, and you also have to edit your template. Here are the steps:

1. Go to "ACP > Users and Groups (tab) > Custom Profile Fields (link) > Click on the settings icon" rename your custom field from "ingame_username" to "ingameusername", since the under score will cause issues.
2. On that same page make sure that the "Display on viewtopic screen" option is checked for the field in question.
3. Go to "ACP > General (tab) > Server Configuration (section) > Load Settings (link)", and make sure that the "Display custom Profile fields on topic pages" radio option is checked.
4. Find the line in "viewtopic_body.html" that contains:

   {postrow.POSTER_FROM}

Underneath it, add the following line (line 184 in phpbb 3.0.10):

```
<!-- IF postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_INGAMEUSERNAME_NAME --><dd><strong>{postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_INGAMEUSERNAME_NAME}:</strong> {postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_INGAMEUSERNAME_VALUE}</dd><!-- ENDIF -->
```

That's it! You will now see the custom field and it's value on the Viewtopic Page.

[image]

Pete

Comment: Hi, I'm using phpbb 3.1.6, but I'm not able to find "{postrow.POSTER_FROM}" string. I have added the string in "<!-- BEGIN custom_fields -->" section.  But, not able to see changes even after purging template cache. Please help me.

Comment: With PHPBB 3.1.x, the PHPBB Team has moved away from modifying template files manually and switched over to extensions instead. Take a look at this link to learn more about writing extensions: https://www.phpbb.com/extensions/writing/